# How to put nodes to variable

Tags: xslt

I have short question.
I have 2 Lines but why it dispays 'mixed' one time?

```
  <xsl:variable name="relItems-nodes">
    <xsl:for-each select="Lines/Line">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($relItems-nodes)">
     mixed
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Could you share your input XML and minimal but complete XSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `relItems-nodes` is a result tree fragment with a root node containing various `Line` elements, the use of `msxsl:node-set($relItems-nodes)` converts that into a node-set with a root node containing various `Line` elements so if you don't want to process the root node but the contained `Line` elements use `<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($relItems-nodes)/Line">...</xsl:for-each>`.

By the way,

```
<xsl:for-each select="Lines/Line">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

could be shortened to `<xsl:copy-of select="Lines/Line"/>`.